# Only the first AirPods Pro I put in my ear works

Tags: airpods

I bought my AirPods 2 months ago and since 2 days they started being weird. Only the AirPod that I put in my ear first works but when I put the other one in it keeps on lagging and bugging and still plays over one AirPod

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you been able to reproduce this issue testing your AirPods with another device? You write `Only the AirPod that I put in my ear first works`, is that true for either the right or left AirPod? Is that string on the screenshot (`u_GHT..`) the name of your AirPods? Did you set that name?

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue with my right AirPod and I bought them about 2 months ago also!!!  I think there may have been a bad batch of AirPods Pro.  I called apple and they sent me a new right AirPod and they work perfectly now.  I suggest doing the same thing.

Also, when you get the replacement, I had to unpair, then reset the AirPods a couple times before it would connect to the new one.

Comment: May be relevant: https://support.apple.com/airpods-pro-service-program-sound-issues

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks.